# SLES 11 SP4 'Resource temporarily unavailable' after upgrade from SP3

Tags: opensuse, sles, thread

After upgrade from SLES 11 sp3 to sp4 I've met the problem while creating threads. Message I got was 'Resource temporarily unavailable'. Is it possible that upgrade changed limits somehow or maybe added something else that may cause this situation? To create thread I use pthread_create.

I've tried changing limits to bigger values but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to increase virtual memory limits, as it has an influence on maximum address space that is reduced with this service pack. You can check this value for specific process in `/proc/<PID>/limits`.